# Return array value

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a bit of a complicated array that I'm working with and I'm not sure how to retrieve one of the values in the array. The array structure is as below and I'm trying to get the 'value'.

```
array ( 
  0 => Drupal\search_api\Query\Condition::__set_state(
    array( 
      'field' => 'title', 
      'value' => 'hello', 
      'operator' => 'CONTAINS', 
    )
  ), 
  )
```

I tried using $array[0]['value'] but it returns NULL.

Any ideas on how to go about this one?

Answer (score 1):

The `Drupal\search_api\Query\Condition::__set_state` there is how `var_export` tells you that there is an *object* in `$array[0]`. The array shown inside that is a view of the *internal* data of that object, which may not be directly accessible at all.

You need to find the documentation or source code for the `Drupal\search_api\Query\Condition` class and see how it provides access to its data. For instance, the access *might* look like this (it probably doesn't, this is an example not a suggestion):

```
echo $array[0]->tellMeTheValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right from the documentation I can see that the access is $array[0]->getValue()